# How to prevent navigation when app is recovering from Tombstone?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have an app where, when the app is tombstoned, I want to restart the app again in it's "new" state on its home screen.

But by default, the wp7 framework wants to navigate you back to whatever page you left off on.

How do you stop this behavior?

Comment: I want to restart the app on the home page.  Not 3 pages deep or wherever was left off

Comment: When coming back from tombstone you could navigate to your home screen and remove the first screen from the backstack.  I think that's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eh, this is what I came up with, and like Shahar says, it is hacky (but does work):

In App.xaml.cs

```
    bool hasLaunched;

    private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
    {
        hasLaunched = true;
    }

    private void Application_Activated(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!hasLaunched) // recovering from a tombstone
            GlobalNavigationService.ToMainPage();
        hasLaunched = true;
    }
```

In the GlobalNavigationService class:

```
    public static async void ToMainPage()
    {
        //CurrentFrame.StopLoading();
        await Observable.FromEventPattern<NavigationEventArgs>(CurrentFrame, "Navigated").Take(1).ToTask();

        SafelyNavigateTo("/ZuneSlotMachine;component/Views/Main/MainPage.xaml");

        await Observable.FromEventPattern<NavigationEventArgs>(CurrentFrame, "Navigated").Take(1).ToTask();

        while (CurrentFrame.BackStack.Count() > 0)
            CurrentFrame.RemoveBackEntry();
    }
```

Basically, it waits for the first navigation to happen, which does not seem to be cancellable even by calling CurrentFrame.StopLoading().  After the first nav, it navigated to my starting page.  After that nav completes, then it removes all entries from the backstack.

It works, but there is a noticeable (1 - 2 second) delay when returning from tombstone.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do this w/o some pretty big hacks. Here's the only way I can personally think of doing this - there may be others.

1. When coming back from tombstone, you will get an ApplicationActivated event. Store some variable that remembers that. Also, reset your global state.
2. Use `NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry` until you reach your first page.
3. If you can "reset" the state of the main page, do that. Otherwise, from your MainPage, in OnNavigateTo, if the static variable you set to remember you just came back is true, use the NavigationService.Navigate() method to again go to the first page of the application. You now have TWO "first" pages in your stack. The first is going to be "dirty" and the second is going to be the "new" one.
4. Reset the global variable that tells you that you just came back from deactivation, but have a second global variable that tells you to crash the app if back is pressed.
5. Hook the BackKey event and kill the app (throw some exception).

I highly recommnend you rethink your app flow - this is some pretty bad mojo.